# .htaccess url rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite a URL.

Let's say you visit http://files.domain.com/uploads/file_name.jpg

How can I use htaccess to write it so I can access it via http://files.domain.com/file_name.jpg?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting following lines in your root .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/[^/]*\.jpg [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*\.jpg)$ /uploads/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: What is the error ?. config error. Looks look I'm too sleepy, fixed one more typo ... try again ..

Comment: Now it works. Now, how can it be changed so it will work with all filetypes?

Comment: @Spencer That would just be a rewrite for everything to /uploads/ is that what you want?

Comment: I upload all my files to the /uploads/ directory. I just want to be able to visit http://files.domain.com/file instead of http://files.domain.com/uploads/file

Comment: @captain giraffe: Rule will work, but I put conds to make it tighter. Second cond is not required,

Comment: @spencer : just change the extensions.