# Rewrite url in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.htaccess url rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424227/htaccess-url-rewrite)

How can I Rewrite URL in .htaccess file

**from**

```
http://example.com/blogs/123/2/blog-title-goes-here
```

**to**

```
http://example.com/blogs/blog-title-goes-here
```

?

Comment: There are an incredible number of similar questions on SO. I've linked to one above. Try going through the huge list of links under the Related header down the right-hand side of this page.

Comment: yeah i know i have firstly searched but not getting satified answer  which matched to my needs..that is why i put new one...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can rewrite to a dynamic URL - I may be wrong however, find out what the original URL rewrites too then edit your question to let us know then I can help

Comment: Yea correct @jake I guess it could be the matter...thanks for confirmation...

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you type `http://example.com/blogs/123/2/blog-title-goes-here` the browser, you got served this page `http://example.com/blogs/blog-title-goes-here` then

```
RewriteRule ^blogs/[0-9]+/[0-9]+/(.*) /blogs/$1 [R,L] #Or just [L] if you don't want a redirect but a simple rewrite.
```

If you mean that the client types `http://example.com/blogs/blog-title-goes-here` and gets redirected to `http://example.com/blogs/123/2/blog-title-goes-here` there are no ways to do it with mod_rewrite since it can't just guess the number 123 an 2 (unless they are static numbers)

Comment: Sorry @M've its not working i want rewrite url and i have checked by replacing [R,L] to [L]..Its not working..well thanks for reply

Comment: @M've Its redirecting fine but i want rewriting..but its rewriting is not working...any other idea..??

Comment: Rewrite/Redirect is just a matter of [R] flag. Redirect means the address got change in the browser bar, rewritte is transparent.

Answer (score -2):

You could do something like this:

`RewriteRule ^blogs/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$ /blogs/article/$3 [NC,L]`

Edited: since I could test now :)

Comment: sorry TNC this is not working..well thanks for reply..

Comment: That's nowhere near what he asked for! :P